# Librería Zuck.js con JSON

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con la librería [Zuck.js](https://github.com/ramon82/zuck.js/blob/master/README.md) que permite crear estados/historias como los de Whatsapp,FB,IG, inicialmente pude generar los estados reemplazando los valores de ejemplo, pero ahora quiero crear mis propios estados con el resultado de un JSON pero no sé como pasar los datos la función, **aquí el código de Zuck:**

```
 /**
 * This function just returns a nice object with the properties built.
 * This could have also been defined itself in the stories array.
 * @param {*} id 
 * @param {*} type 
 * @param {*} length 
 * @param {*} src 
 * @param {*} preview 
 * @param {*} link 
 * @param {*} seen 
 * @param {*} time 
 */
function buildItem(id, type, length, src, preview, link, seen, time) {
// Using object short-hand (id: id)
  return {
    id,
    type,
    length,
    src,
    preview,
    link,
    seen,
    time,
  };
}

/**
 * Creates Zuck stories. 
 */
const stories = new Zuck('stories', {
  backNative: true,
  autoFullScreen: 'false',
  skin: 'Snapgram',
  avatars: 'true',
  list: false,
  cubeEffect: 'true',
  localStorage: true,
  stories: [
    {//aqui se crea la historia para cada usuario (ref: img1)
      id: 'vision',
      photo: 'logo.jpg', 
      name: 'AIM',
      link: '',
      lastUpdated: 1492665454,
      items: [ //aqui se llena la historia con fotos o videos (ref: img2)
        buildItem('1', 'photo', 3, 'img/1.jpg', '', false, 1492665454),
        buildItem('2', 'photo', 3, 'img/2.jpg', '', '', false, 1492665454),
        buildItem('3', 'photo', 3, 'img/3.jpg', '', '', false, 1492665454),
      ],
    },{
      id: 'visionX',
      photo: 'img/avatar-1.png',
      name: 'PRUEBA',
      link: '',
      lastUpdated: 1492665454,
      items: [
        buildItem('1', 'photo', 3, 'img/1.png', '', false, 1492665454),
        buildItem('2', 'photo', 3, 'img/2.png', '', '', false, 1492665454),
        buildItem('3', 'photo', 3, 'img/3.png', '', '', false, 1492665454),
      ],
    }
    ],
});
```

**IMG1**
[image: Ejemplo de listado de historias]

[image: Foto dentro de la historia]
**IMG2**

Al pasar los datos manualmente se crean las historias, pero le quiero pasar el JSON para que se generen dinamicamente.

En el mismo archivo tengo un ajax que me devuelve un json

**Código Ajax:**

```
    $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/lavecina2/usuarios/historias',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item){//aqui pretendo imprimir todos los datos uno a uno dependiendo la cantidad de resultados
      {id = data[i].usuario
      photo = data[i].nick
      }
    })
  },
  error: function() {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
    }
})
```

El JSON viene así:

```
[{
    "usuario": "12",
    "nick": "milf",
    "items": [{
        "id": "1",
        "ruta": "IMG-20160215-WA0017.jpeg",
        "fecha": "2019-08-02 03:11:18",
        "tipo": "3"
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "ruta": "IMG-20160409-WA0062.jpg",
        "fecha": "2019-08-02 04:15:00",
        "tipo": "3"
    }]
}, {
    "usuario": "11",
    "nick": "kata",
    "items": [{
        "id": "5",
        "ruta": "IMG-20160409-WA0060.jpg",
        "fecha": "2019-08-02 04:15:00",
        "tipo": "3"
    }]
}]
```

A este JSON le puedo añadir más datos necesarios para generar la historia, lo que aún no he logrado entender es como pasar ese resultado a la función `const stories = new Zuck()` para que se creen las historias

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia, comentario de como pasar los datos. Saludos!

Como dato extra, uso: Codeigniter y Mysql en el Backend

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Luego de implementar el código sugerido por la respuesta del compañero, me genera un error en la librería, parece que no puede leer los items, adjunto código:

```
const stories = new Zuck('stories', {
  backNative: true,
  autoFullScreen: 'false',
  skin: 'Snapgram',
  avatars: 'true',
  list: false,
  cubeEffect: 'true',
  localStorage: true,
});
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/lavecina2/usuarios/historias',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);

            $.each(data, function(index) {
              //console.log(data[index].items)
                stories.addItem(index, data[index]);
               //buildItem(data[index].items);
               // console.log(stories.addItem(index, data[index]));

            });
        },
  error: function() {
        console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
    }
});
```

El error que me genera es:

```
zuck.min.js:formatted:596 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined
    at r.d.addItem (zuck.min.js:formatted:596)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:49)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:367)
    at Object.success (main.js:47)
    at fire (jquery.js:3291)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3421)
    at done (jquery.js:9533)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9785)
```

La línea de código de la librería donde muestra el error es:

```
d.addItem = function(a, b, c) {
                a = f("#".concat(p, ' > [data-id="').concat(a, '"]'));
                var d = v.createElement("li");
                d.className = e(b, "seen") ? "seen" : "";
                d.setAttribute("data-id", e(b, "id"));
                d.innerHTML = '<a href="'.concat(e(b, "src"), '" data-link="').concat(e(b, "link"), '" data-linkText="').concat(e(b, "linkText"), '" data-time="').concat(e(b, "time"), '" data-type="').concat(e(b, "type"), '" data-length="').concat(e(b, "length"), '"><img src="').concat(e(b, "preview"), '"></a>');
                b = a.querySelectorAll(".items")[0]; //linea con el error
                c ? b.appendChild(d) : E(b, d);
                U(a)
            }
```

Por último, el JSON viene así:

```
[{
"id":"11",
"photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/lavecina2\/assets\/images\/fufa.jpg",
"name":"kata",
"link":"http:\/\/localhost\/lavecina2\/kata",
"lastUpdated":1565242287,
"seen":false,
"items":[
{
"id":"5",
"type":"photo",
"length:":3,
"src":"IMG-20160409-WA0060.jpg",
"preview":"",
"link":"",
"seen":false,
"time":"2019-08-02 04:15:00"
}]
},{
"id":"12",
"photo":"http:\/\/localhost\/lavecina2\/assets\/images\/firma_andrea.png",
"name":"Milf",
"link":"http:\/\/localhost\/lavecina2\/Milf",
"lastUpdated":1565242287,
"seen":false,
"items":[{
"id":"1",
"type":"photo",
"length:":3,
"src":"IMG-20160215-WA0017.jpeg",
"preview":"",
"link":"",
"seen":false,
"time":"2019-08-02 03:11:18"
},{
"id":"6",
"type":"photo",
"length:":3,
"src":"IMG-20160409-WA0062.jpg",
"preview":"",
"link":"",
"seen":false,
"time":"2019-08-02 04:15:00"
}]
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que tienes en tu actualización es porque estás utilizando el método addItem:

```
stories.addItem(storyId, {item object});
```

que es para añadir/remover **items de una historia.**

Mientras que el método para añadir/actualizar una historia  es:

```
stories.update({item object});
```

Creo que el nombre de los métodos da paso a la confusión.

Probé cambiando el método en tu código:

```
 $.each(data, function(index) {
              //console.log(data[index].items)
                stories.addItem(index, data[index]);
               //buildItem(data[index].items);
               // console.log(stories.addItem(index, data[index]));

            });
```

por:

```
$.each(data, function (index) {
            //console.log(data[index].items)
            stories.update(data[index]);
            //buildItem(data[index].items);
            // console.log(stories.addItem(index, data[index]));

          });
```

y funcionó sin problemas.

Comment: Estimado, efectivamente funciona, lo acabo de probar y era ese el inconveniente. Muchas gracias! Marcado como respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Una vez iniciado zuck.js, puedes añadir nuevos stories así:

```
stories.addItem(storyId, {item object});
```

Haz que el JSON tenga un formato similar al que se muestra en [el ejemplo](https://ramon.codes/projects/zuck.js/index.html) de la propia web de zuck.js:

```
{
    id: "",               // story id
    photo: "",            // story photo (or user photo)
    name: "",             // story name (or user name)
    link: "",             // story link (useless on story generated by script)
    lastUpdated: "",      // last updated date in unix time format
    seen: false,          // set true if user has opened - if local storage is used, you don't need to care about this 

    items: [              // array of items
        // story item example
        {
            id: "",       // item id
            type: "",     // photo or video
            length: 3,    // photo timeout or video length in seconds - uses 3 seconds timeout for images if not set
            src: "",      // photo or video src
            preview: "",  // optional - item thumbnail to show in the story carousel instead of the story defined image
            link: "",     // a link to click on story
            linkText: "", // link text
            time: "",     // optional a date to display with the story item. unix timestamp are converted to "time ago" format
            seen: false   // set true if current user was read - if local storage is used, you don't need to care about this
        }
    ]
}
```

No he podido probar el código, pero con estos cambios y añadiendo los stories a la vez que se recorre el JSON debería funcionar:

```
<script>
    const stories = new Zuck('stories', {
        backNative: true,
        autoFullScreen: 'false',
        skin: 'Snapgram',
        avatars: 'true',
        list: false,
        cubeEffect: 'true',
        localStorage: true
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/lavecina2/usuarios/historias',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                stories.addItem(index, data[index]);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he probado con el código y me marca un error, actualizaré la pregunta para que lo veas.